# Асинхронный запуск функции

Tags: python, многопоточность, asyncio

У меня есть функция `update_db`, которая обновляет базу данных. Функция `get_product` работает секунд 10. Если у меня будет 100 товаров, то функция `update_db` будет выполняться очень долго. Как можно запустить функцию `get_product` сразу ко всем товарам асинхронно?

```py
def update_db():
    for product in products:
        url = product[6]
        title, price, availability = get_product(url, mode=True)
        cur.execute('UPDATE products_product SET title = %s, price = %s, availability = %s WHERE url = %s',
                    (title, price, availability, url))
        conn.commit()
```

get_product

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver


def get_product(url_website: str, mode: bool = True):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument(f"user-agent=project-user-agent")
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    options.headless = mode

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path="Путь_до_драйвера",
        options=options
    )

    title = ''
    price = 0
    availability = True

    try:
        driver.get(url=url_website)

        content = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

        title = soup.find('h1', class_='title').text

        price_str = soup.find('span', class_='price__main-value').text

        test = soup.find('p', class_='product-sold-out-text')
        if test:
            availability = False
        else:
            availability = True
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f'Неизвестная ошибка: {ex}')
    finally:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()

    return title, price, availability
```

Comment: А что делает функция get_product, откуда она получает данные и каким образом. что бы функция стала асинхронной, надо переделать саму функцию внутри. Например заменить работу с requests на aiohttp, в случае если она получает данные по протоколу http

Comment: Функция get_product парсит данные с сайта. Сейчас прикреплю

Comment: Это ни о чем не говорит. надо смотреть как именно она получает данные, менять получение данных на асинхронное. а потом еще смотреть не занимает ли сам парсинг после получения данных слишком много процессорного времени. А если занимает, то держит ли при этом блокировку GIL.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос функцию get_product

Comment: А webdriver умеет быть асинхронным ?

Comment: Я не знаю. Это возможно или нет?

Comment: И еще бы понять что именно занимает 10 секунд, если почти все время уходит на то что бы ответил сайт на который идет запрос, то тогда надо понять, а не будет ли тот сайт отвечать например 30 секунд в случае если отправить на него 2 запроса параллельно, т.е. не замедлит ли паралеллеьная работа его. Если 2 разпроса не замедляет, то понять сколько параллельных запросов он в принципе может выдержать без серьезной деградации произовдительности

Comment: Я то же не знаю, надо смотреть что такое этот webdriver, читать документацию на него, смотреть есть ли в нем функции, которые можно вызывать асинхронно

Comment: в любом случае что бы что то оптимизировать надо понимать характер нагрузки. Потому что асинхронность в принципе уместна только в случае если имеет место ожидание внешнего события, например получения данных по сети. Если же долгое время работы связано не с ожиданием, а с работой процессора, то в зависимости от того происходит это под GIL или нет выбирать либо мультипоточность либо даже мультипроцессность

Comment: По времени больше всего занимает это: driver.get(url=url_website). Он вообще по разному работает. Может 5 секунд, может 20

Comment: Я так понял webdriver это селениеум. судя по документации он не умеет выполняться асинхронно. Его надо выполнять в потоках, смотреть в сторону thread pool. Можно при этом и asyncio задействовать (но с потоками) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303797/python-webdriver-and-asyncio

Comment: selenium в асинхронку не смогет. Желательно selenium заменить на что-то другое.